# Javascript/HTML: Manipulate body text without innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have some HTML representing a bibliography with a few hundred paragraphs, each of which looks like:

```
<p>Some text, doi:<a href="https://doi.org/some_doi">some_doi</a>.</p>
```

Currently, I enter the two occurrences of the DOI by hand for each new `<p>` entry, but that's not very efficient, and I'd like to replace with a script to generate the `<a href>` for each entry.  I can do so using `innerHTML`, but that requires generating an `id` for each, and a corresponding script in `head`, which is even less efficient.

I've tried to make a single `head` script to replace this workflow:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function substituteDOI(myDOI) {
      return `doi:<a href="${myDOI}">${myDOI}</a>`;
    }
  </script>
```

and calling it inline in `body`:

```
<p>Some text, <script type="text/javascript">substituteDOI('test');</script>.</p>
```

but that script returns nothing to the `<p>` element at all, even when just using `return 'test'` , or some similar dummy text. The browser console likewise returns no errors to debug with, and it's clear that the source itself isn't being updated. What I'd like is, functionally, an inline way to substitute in a given string (and do some simple concatenation on it).

Is this possible?   I realize that using something like a template engine would be more well-suited, but I don't want to have to rework the entire website page just for this.

Comment: You can use ```document.write()```, but it will replace all the content in your html file. If so, you still need to use innerHTML, but since you don't want to generate *id* for each of them, use ```querySelectorAll``` instead.

Comment: Exactly, I ran into that issue right away.  I'll try `querySelectorAll`, but the issue that jumps to mind is that each `<p>` element has a different URL for the a href - grabbing them all like this would only be able to do the same substitution for them all, no?  Logic testing could be used, but that would be a big logic tree, and not really a time saver.

Comment: Yes, using ```querySelectorAll``` and replacing a fixed string wouldn't work if each paragraph contains a different DOI, but you can modify the script to extract the DOI from each paragraph and use that to generate the ```<a>``` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering..

> I'll try querySelectorAll, but the issue that jumps to mind is that each `<p>` element has a different URL for the a href.

Then, you can use a regex to extract the DOI from each paragraph. The regex `/doi:(\S+)/` will match the string **doi:** followed by one or more non-whitespace characters, which should capture the DOI.

Example approach;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function substituteDOI(myDOI) {
  return `doi:<a href="${myDOI}">${myDOI}</a>`;
 }

 var paragraphs = document.querySelectorAll("p");
 paragraphs.forEach(function(paragraph) {
  var text = paragraph.innerHTML;
  var doiMatch = text.match(/doi:(\S+)/);
  if (doiMatch) {
    var doi = doiMatch[1]; // The DOI is the first capturing group
    var newText = text.replace("doi:" + doi, substituteDOI(doi));
    paragraph.innerHTML = newText;
  }
 });
</script>
```

This approach allows you to replace all DOI's in your html with a single script, without having to generate an id for each paragraph or a corresponding script in the head. It also avoids the need to rework the entire website page.

Answer (score 0):

Use `document.write()` to insert the value of the function after the `<script>`

```
<p>Some text, <script type="text/javascript">document.write(substituteDOI('test'));</script>.</p>
```